# I want to handle error service, Now i want to manually put single error in my service I want to make it automatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to handle error service, Now i want to manually put single error in my service I want to make it automatically.

```
'use strict';
angular.module('nexoolApp.errorservice', ['nexoolApp.config'])
  .service('Errorservices',['nexoolConfig', function (nexoolConfig) {
    //console.log('Inside Errorservices');
    var showmessage=nexoolConfig.defaultErrorMessage;
    this.geterrordetails = function(data)
    {
        if(data.errors) {
            if (data.errors.USER_NOT_PROVIDED) {
                showmessage = data.errors.USER_NOT_PROVIDED.message;
            } else if (data.errors.ADMIN_NOT_PROVIDED) {
                showmessage = data.errors.ADMIN_NOT_PROVIDED.message;
            }
}
        return showmessage;
    };

}]);
```

Comment: I am not able to understand your question.Please elaborate it further and specify what you are expecting as an outcome

Comment: Every time i need to add else if any new error we get from api so i want to automate that problem

Comment: So, the error priority is `USER_NOT_PROVIDED` is preferred over `ADMIN_NOT_PROVIDED` while showing the error message ? Plz confirm on this . I mean if it has  `data.errors.USER_NOT_PROVIDED` it wont look for any other error message.

Comment: Yes correct at one time it will get only one error

Comment: Reason, I am asking this is because you got to have a priority number decided in your case so that the `error` which has the highest priority among all will be selected and shown. Right now, you are deciding it based on `if` `else` code. I hope you are getting my point

Comment: no i will get any one error from this when i submit the form at that i want to show this message to rollebar

Comment: Getting error for property not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the scenario you have described:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('nexoolApp.errorservice', ['nexoolApp.config'])
  .service('Errorservices',['nexoolConfig', function (nexoolConfig) {
    //console.log('Inside Errorservices');
    var showmessage=nexoolConfig.defaultErrorMessage;
    this.geterrordetails = function(data)
    {
        if(data.errors) {
            for ( var property in data.errors ) {
                showmessage = data.errors[property]['message'];
                break;
            }
        }
        return showmessage;
    };

}]);
```

Comment: I am getting error property is not defined please help

Comment: @ManishTiwari: Check the edited answer, You need to add `var` in for loop. see if it works now

Comment: Thanks shashank it's working additionally can you please help if i want to use IF condition instead of FOR

Comment: using `if` and `else` is never recommended unless you have no other options. Its makes your code less reusable and hard to manage.  You can check about this on google. For every change that you make in API, you'll have to add 4-5 lines of `else` code which is bad. It's good that you recognize this issue early and posted a question to overcome it. 

Please mark it as an answer & **upvote** so that it can help others as well